# Exploiting the joint density when averaging measurements

Tags: repeated-measures, error, joint-distribution, measurement-error, error-propagation

I have two measurements of a quantity from two different sensors, each with their own variance based on the sensors' specifications, etc. From collecting a lot of training data, I have access to the joint distribution of measurements from the two sensors.

When I collect a new measurement, I would like to estimate both the quantity and my error in the estimate, exploiting the fact that I have this prior knowledge about how the sensors behave together. For example, my joint distribution tells me that the sensors typically agree quite well - if I make a measurement where the sensors disagree considerably, the reported error should be higher since likely something went wrong. Propagating the error when averaging the two sensor readings yields a **constant** variance (even when treating them as [correlated variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168971/variance-of-an-average-of-random-variables)).

What is the right way to compute the error in this case?