# Variability Reduction Using Square Roots

Tags: machine-learning, variability

I am averaging volumes over a couple of shapes using different orientations and plane views. I think I read somewhere that the variability can be reduced in proportional to the square root of the number of shapes that is being used for the average, but I can't find any references to this. Is that statement about variability reduction true? If not, what is the actual statement (with reference provided)?

Comment: Variability of what?  The sample arithmetic mean?  If that's what you have in mind, it depends on the distributions of those volumes.  For instance, if the shapes are spheres where the arctangents of their radii are uniformly distributed, then the more volumes you measure, the *more* variable the average is.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/168991/42952) (and in many other places), if you take the average of $n$ different variables each with a variance of $\sigma^2$, and so a standard deviation of $\sigma$, the average has a variance of $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, or a standard deviation of $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. However, this is about averaging together **variables**, not averaging individual data points (e.g. different specific shapes), so it's not clear it applies to your situation.